# ¿Cómo hacer for embemido en otro en VUEJS?

Tags: php, json, laravel, loops, vue.js

Estoy obteniendo la informacion a traves de json en un template de vuejs que hice para poder crear una tabla con ciertos datos, estos datos son:
Perfiles, los cuales contiene permisos, pueden ser 1 o muchos permisos, y tengo que hacer una tabla en la cual se muestre en la primer columna el nombre del perfil, y con la propiedad rowspan de html decirle cuantas filas tendra que combinar segun la cantidad de permisos, que los permisos a su ves contienen otros datos.

```
    <template>
    <table id="user_list" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Perfil</th>
              <th>Permiso</th>
              <th>crear</th>
              <th>leer</th>
              <th>modificar</th>
              <th>eliminar</th>
              <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

   <tr v-for="perfil in perfiles">
     <td> {{ perfil.nombre_perfil }}  </td>
     <tr v-for="permiso in perfil.permisos">
         <td> {{ permiso.nombre_permiso }}</td>
         <td> {{ permiso.create }}</td>
         <td> {{ permiso.read }}</td>
         <td> {{ permiso.update }} </td>
         <td> {{ permiso.delete }} </td>
         <td> <button class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x"></button></td>
     </tr>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

el json lo recibo en el array perfiles es donde estan todos los datos, pero al momento de hacer esto asi el error que me sale es:

```
    [Vue warn]: Property or method "perfil" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option
```

luego el error de abajo es:

```
  [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'permisos' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los errores surgen debido a que tienes errores en el `markup`.

- Un [`tr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/tr) no puede contener otro `tr`.

### Solución:

Podrías hacerlo modificando el `markup` así:

- Por cada `perfile` creamos un `tbody`, ya que un [`table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) puede contener cero o mas `tbody`.
- Por cada `permiso` del `perfile` creamos un `tr`.

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#user_list',
  data: {
    perfiles: [{
      nombre_perfil: 'Juan',
      permisos: [{
        nombre_permiso: 'Usuarios',
        create: true,
        read: true,
        update: true,
        delete: true
      },{
        nombre_permiso: 'Noticias',
        create: true,
        read: true,
        update: true,
        delete: true
      }]
    },{
      nombre_perfil: 'Pedro',
      permisos: [{
        nombre_permiso: 'Usuarios',
        create: false,
        read: true,
        update: false,
        delete: false
      },{
        nombre_permiso: 'Noticias',
        create: true,
        read: true,
        update: true,
        delete: true
      }]
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.1/dist/vue.js"></script>
<table id="user_list" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Perfil</th>
      <th>Permiso</th>
      <th>crear</th>
      <th>leer</th>
      <th>modificar</th>
      <th>eliminar</th>
      <th>Accion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody v-for="perfil in perfiles">
    <tr>
      <td v-bind:rowspan="perfil.permisos.length + 1"> {{ perfil.nombre_perfil }} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="permiso in perfil.permisos">
      <td> {{ permiso.nombre_permiso }}</td>
      <td> {{ permiso.create }}</td>
      <td> {{ permiso.read }}</td>
      <td> {{ permiso.update }} </td>
      <td> {{ permiso.delete }} </td>
      <td> <button class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x"></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```